# Heroic Federation-like organization gains the ability to predict entropy hijinks ensue

Tags: story-identification, novel

There is some sort of Federation-like organization, with agents who are "lone wolf" types.

Some of the details I remember:

- Each agent has an invisible, small "god" on their shoulder. They are referred to as "gods", and one of the tricks they can perform for the agent is to allow FTL communication to other agents through the other side's god.
- Early in the novel, a new science of predicting entropy gives them insight that entropy is somehow being controlled by an alien force, and used to wipe out the machines they need to "predict" when these events will occur.
- A young woman has been bred to have the ability to predict entropy without the machines, becomes a sort of sidekick.
- The alien force turns out to be a civilization soon to experience a *Big Crunch*, and they have to consume the mass of about 10 of our suns every second simply to control entropy in the other universe. It is never explained if they are merely our future, or a previous incarnation of the universe, or somehow separate entirely. Since they're close to the Big Crunch though, 10 solar masses isn't all that expensive.

I read this 10 or 15 years ago, a used book, the style of the cover made me think cheesy 1970s (and maybe even offensively sexist 1970s... but I may be confusing that with another).

On a scale of 1 to 10, with 10 being pulptastic, this novel was easily a 853.6. Not a classic, not even just a good read, but almost atrociously bad. If it were a Star Wars character, it would be Jar Jar on bath salts.

Not EE Doc Smith. Definitely inspired by him though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's [*The Chaos Weapon*](http://www.examiner.com/article/book-review-the-chaos-weapon-by-colin-kapp) by Colin Kapp. Quoting from the linked page:

> *The Chaos Weapon* concerns the efforts of Space Marshall Jym Wildheit to find and destroy what is causing improbable deaths and destruction in the Galactic Federation. The great minds in the Federation are dying off at a statistically improbable rate, and Wildheit is assigned to find what is causing these occurrences and to eliminate the threat to humanity.
>
> Along the way he is assigned a young girl called Roamer, to aid him in his quest. She comes from a planet called Maya (reminiscent of the Vedic Goddess Maya Mistress of Illusions) where a sect of people calling themselves Sensitives went to conduct self-breeding studies and work to enhance and foster paranormal seeming talents and skills.
>
> The Space Marshalls have a symbiotic relationship with an extra dimensional entity which is a god of sorts. It has a limited control over the passage of time from a subjective and objective perspective. Where the god, Cuol in the case of Jym Wildheit, comes from is never discussed in the book at all. Other aspects such as travelling between planets are handled in a simple driving a car feeling. The overall sense is the technology is there because it is in the future.

Comment: The link's image of the cover clinches it. This is it.